# Detectar si un elemento tiene un atributo creado

Tags: javascript

En el programa que estoy haciendo (el juego de mesa del memory), necesito comprobar si un elemento tiene el atributo `data-number`, sin embargo utilizar `hasAttributte("data-number")` no funciona, siempre me devuelve que no existe, aunque el elemento si que lo tenga.

Este error ocurre porque hay algunas imagenes extraidas de lorem picsum que no funcionan correctamente. Sin embargo no se por que ocurre esto. He intentado controlar el error para generar una nueva imagen si ha fallado en cargar pero no lo he conseguido, por eso mi siguiente alternativa es controlar si los elementos tienen el atributo `data-number`, que se genera cuando la imagen se carga correctamente.

También me saltan siempre 8 errores en la consola cuando se ejecuta el programa y 1 mas por cada par de cartas que han fallado en generarse, no se ni por que salen esos errores ni como hacer para quitarlos.

```js
let side = 4; //Cambia el numero de casillas por lado, poner numeros pares

let gridContainer = document.createElement("div");
gridContainer.className = "grid-container";
gridContainer.style.display = "grid";
gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = getGridColumns();
gridContainer.style.gap = "10px";
gridContainer.style.padding = "10px";
gridContainer.style.textAlign = "center";
gridContainer.style.justifyContent = "center";

let area = ((side < 2) ? 2 : side) ** 2;
for (let i = 0; i < area; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("div");
    item.className = "grid-item";
    item.id = i;
    item.style.width = "200px";
    item.style.height = "200px";
    item.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    item.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    item.style.border = "1px solid gray";

    gridContainer.appendChild(item);
}

let cont = document.createElement("div");

let text = document.createElement("div");
cont.style.textAlign = "center";
cont.textContent = "Parejas Encontradas: ";
cont.style.fontSize = "30px";

let points = document.createElement("div");
points.id = "points";
points.style.fontSize = "30px";
points.textContent = "0";

cont.appendChild(text);
cont.appendChild(points);

document.body.appendChild(cont);
document.body.appendChild(gridContainer);

function getGridColumns() {
    let autos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ((side < 2) ? 2 : side); i++) {
        autos.push("auto");
    }
    return autos.join(" ");
}

let items = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
let half = items.length / 2;
let contador = 0;

let used = new Array(items.length).fill(undefined);
//console.log(items.length, used)

loadArray();
//console.log(used.toString());

items.forEach((item, i) => {
    loadImage(item, i);
});

createBackground();

function loadArray() {
    let flag = true;

    while (used.includes(undefined)) {
        let number;
        do {
            number = ~~(Math.random() * 400);
            flag = checkImage(number, flag);
            console.log("numero");
        } while (used.includes(number) && flag);

        let nPos;
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            do {
                nPos = ~~(Math.random() * used.length);
            } while (used[nPos] !== undefined);
            used[nPos] = number;
        }
    }
}

function checkImage(image, flag) {
    let test = new Image();

    test.onload = function () {
        flag = true;
    };

    test.onerror = function () {
        flag = false;
    };

    test.src = `url(https://picsum.photos/id/${image}/200)`;
    return flag;
}

function loadImage(item, index) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
        item.setAttribute("data-number", `${used[index]}`);
        item.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://picsum.photos/id/${used[index]}/200)`;
    };
    image.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${used[index]}/200`;
}

function createBackground() {
    let cardDiv = document.createElement("div");
    cardDiv.style.width = "100%";
    cardDiv.style.height = "100%";
    cardDiv.style.borderRadius = "15px";
    cardDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.picsum.photos/id/43/200)";

    items.forEach(card => {
        let divClone = cardDiv.cloneNode(true);
        card.addEventListener("click", cardClickEvent);
        card.appendChild(divClone);
    });
}

let numbers = [];

function cardClickEvent(event) {
    if (contador >= 2) {
    } else {
        if (event.target.className !== "grid-item") {
            event.target.setAttribute("hidden", true);

            //console.log(event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-number"))
            numbers.push(event.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-number"));

            contador++;
        }
        if (contador === 2) {
            //console.log(numbers);
            if (numbers[0] === numbers[1]) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let selected = document
                        .querySelectorAll("[data-number='" + numbers[0] + "']")

                    selected.forEach(i => {
                        i.style.backgroundImage = "url(./resources/ok.png)"
                    });

                    contador = 0;
                    numbers = [];
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                        let cards = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number='" + numbers[i] + "']")
                        cards.forEach(card => {
                            if (card.children[0].hasAttribute("hidden")) {
                                card.children[0].removeAttribute("hidden");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    contador = 0;
                    numbers = [];
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Por alguna razon la consola del snippet de stackoverflow no esta mostrando los errores que aparecen al cargar la imagen, asi que adjunto una captura de pantalla para que podais ver a lo que me refiero
[image: Error al cargar imagen desde lorem picsum]

Comment: Los data attributes se pueden chequear con `Element.dataset` en tu caso:  `Element.dataset.number`

Comment: Entonces utilizando cualquier atributo `data-X` puedo acceder a el usando `Element.dataset.X`?

Comment: @ffflabs , He probado a hacer la comparacion con el dataset que me has dicho pero me salen undefined en todos los items, he colocado un `console.log()` en el `foreach` del metodo `createBackground()` y parece que no funciona. Siempre devuelve un `undefined`. Cabe aclarar que me he asegurado que los elementos tengan el atributo data-number siempre y efectivamente lo tienen.

Comment: Ah, pero no debieras usar `item.setAttribute("data-number", used[index]);`  sino `item.dataset.number = used[index]` Y de paso, te pediría que probaras si cambiando `number` por `numero` te funciona, porque `number` es un tipo, y puede que estés chocando con una palabra reservada

Comment: Hola, he cambiado todos los `setAttribute` de number por `dataset` y cambiado el nombre de `number` a `numero` pero sigue sin funcionar, continua devolviendo `undefined`